# How to query tables in Views/Blade file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm having a set of `array` which stores the `id` of the `blog post`, I want to display the `blog` post with the `id` present in the `array`, I can't pass it through the `controller` as I'm passing lot of data to the views and blog post view is called dynamically, In my controller I'm getting all the post and passing through the view:

```
$blogpost = Post::all();

'blogpost' => $blogpost //data passed in return view
```

Now in view I'm having a `foreach loop` and suppose I want to get the image of that particular post I'm trying to do:

```
@foreach($contents->blogid as $blogid)
    <?php

        $blog = $blogpost->findOrFail($blogid);

    ?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <article class="post post-masonry">
        <div class="post-image">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{{ $blog->featured_image }}" alt="">
                <div class="image-extras">
                    <a href="#" class="post-gallery"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </article>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting an error

> Method findOrFail does not exist

Moreover if I'm changing `findOrFail` to:

```
$blog = $blogpost->find($blogid);
```

I'm getting an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Help me out guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be mixing native PHP  and blade templates.

Instead, let blade do the work for you! :)

```
@foreach($contents->blogid as $blogid)

..
<img src="{!! \App\Post::findOrFail($blogid)->featured_image; !!}" alt="">
..

@endforeach
```

You don't even need to pass the 'blogpost' variable, as long as you have the correct route to your Post class. I used App\Post, but for you it may be different.

Comment: Thanks it helped. But everytime I'll have to query out the table, suppose i want to add title, again i need to query out same for the title thats why I wanted to have `blogpost`

Comment: Ideally what you want to do is create a relationship between your Content and Post classes, so then you can do @foreach($contents as $content) and user $content->post->title and so on. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

`Post::all()` will return an array of Post objects. So just pass that array to your blade template and loop through each `Post` of that array. You should also change the variable name to blogpost**s**.

#### PHP

```
$blogposts = Post::all();

return view('blog.index', ['blogposts' => $blogposts]);
```

#### Blade

```
@foreach ($blogposts as $blogpost)
    <p>{{ $blogpost->id }}</p>
    <p>{{ $blogpost->featured_image }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`findOrFail` or only `find` aren't functions native PHP. You can try statically call, but I think that your problem is easily resolve with Laravel Relationship, your code will be more than clean.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

sorry, first steps with English.